# Why does the resolution vary depending on what page I am (html/css) Chrome only

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a website with different pages. But the resolution varies depending on which page I am on. This screws with my navbar.

My head looks like the following:

Index:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Index</title>
  <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="../img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="../js/javascript.js">
</head> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>brand</title>
  <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="../img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="../js/javascript.js">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
    <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
    <button 
      class="navbar-toggler" 
      type="button" 
      data-toggle="collapse" 
      data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    
    <!-- Brand -->
    <div class="contains-brand-icon">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <img src="../img/Web-brand.png" loading="lazy" srcset="../img/Web-brand-p-500.png 500w, ../img/Web-brand-p-800.png 800w, ../img/Web-brand-p-1080.png 1080w, ../img/Web-brand.png 1590w" alt="" height="40" id="brand-icon-navbar" class="justify-content-center">
      </a>
    </div>
  
    
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="brand-app.html">BrandApp</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">brand für Unternehmen</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">brand für Organisationen</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kampangen</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Über uns</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Support</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="fixed-top">
    <nav>
      <div class="navBar">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="../img/Web-brand.png" loading="lazy" srcset="../img/Web-brand-p-500.png 500w, ../img/Web-brand-p-800.png 800w, ../img/Web-brand-p-1080.png 1080w, ../img/Web-brand.png 1590w" alt="" id="navbar-icon-brand"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="brand-app.html">BrandApp</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">brand für Unternehmen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">brand für Organisationen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kampangen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Über uns</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="introduction-brand">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="introduction-brand-innerpart">
          <h1 class="heading">brand App</h1>
          <div class="sub-heading">Spenden wird kostenlos.</div>
          <div class="sub-sub-heading">Ohne Anmeldung, versteckte Kosten oder Abonnements.</div>
          <div class="linking">
            <a href="index.html">Weitere Infos &gt;</a>
            <a href="index.html">Herunterladen &gt;</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="cut-phones">
          <div id="cut-phones" class="col-sm-12 mobile-presentation">
            <img src="../img/smartmockups_kldnit2k.png" loading="lazy" width="310" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 100vw, 310px" srcset="../img/smartmockups_kldnit2k-p-500.png 500w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnit2k-p-800.png 800w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnit2k-p-1080.png 1080w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnit2k.png 1570w" alt="" class="mobile-presentation-leftest">
            <img src="../img/smartmockups_kldnk32x.png" loading="lazy" width="350" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 100vw, 350px" srcset="../img/smartmockups_kldnk32x-p-500.png 500w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnk32x-p-800.png 800w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnk32x-p-1080.png 1080w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnk32x.png 1570w" alt="" class="mobile-presentation-left">
            <img src="../img/smartmockups_kldneqvz.png" loading="lazy" width="310" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 100vw, 310px" srcset="../img/smartmockups_kldneqvz-p-500.png 500w, ../img/smartmockups_kldneqvz-p-800.png 800w, ../img/smartmockups_kldneqvz-p-1080.png 1080w, ../img/smartmockups_kldneqvz.png 1571w" alt="" class="mobile-presentation-rightest">
            <img src="../img/smartmockups_kldnfsiz.png" loading="lazy" width="350" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 100vw, 350px" srcset="../img/smartmockups_kldnfsiz-p-500.png 500w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnfsiz-p-800.png 800w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnfsiz-p-1080.png 1080w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnfsiz.png 1571w" alt="" class="mobile-presentation-right">
            <img src="../img/smartmockups_kldnld5u.png" loading="lazy" width="380" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 100vw, 380px" srcset="../img/smartmockups_kldnld5u-p-500.png 500w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnld5u-p-800.png 800w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnld5u-p-1080.png 1080w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnld5u.png 1480w" alt="" class="mobile-presentation-centre">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

SecondPage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>brand App</title>
  <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="../img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="../js/javascript.js">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
    <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
    <button 
      class="navbar-toggler" 
      type="button" 
      data-toggle="collapse" 
      data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    
    <!-- Brand -->
    <div class="contains-brand-icon">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <img src="../img/Web-brand.png" loading="lazy" srcset="../img/Web-brand-p-500.png 500w, ../img/Web-brand-p-800.png 800w, ../img/Web-brand-p-1080.png 1080w, ../img/Web-brand.png 1590w" alt="" height="40" id="brand-icon-navbar" class="justify-content-center">
      </a>
    </div>
  
    
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">BrandApp</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">brand für Unternehmen</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">brand für Organisationen</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kampangen</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Über uns</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Support</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="fixed-top">
    <nav>
      <div class="navBar">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="../img/Web-brand.png" loading="lazy" srcset="../img/Web-brand-p-500.png 500w, ../img/Web-brand-p-800.png 800w, ../img/Web-brand-p-1080.png 1080w, ../img/Web-brand.png 1590w" alt="" id="navbar-icon-brand"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">BrandApp</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">brand für Unternehmen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">brand für Organisationen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kampangen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Über uns</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="introduction-brand-app">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 mobile-presentation-brand-app">
                <img src="../img/smartmockups_kldnit2k.png" loading="lazy" width="310" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 100vw, 310px" srcset="../img/smartmockups_kldnit2k-p-500.png 500w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnit2k-p-800.png 800w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnit2k-p-1080.png 1080w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnit2k.png 1570w" alt="" class="mobile-presentation-leftest-brand-app">
                <img src="../img/smartmockups_kldnk32x.png" loading="lazy" width="350" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 100vw, 350px" srcset="../img/smartmockups_kldnk32x-p-500.png 500w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnk32x-p-800.png 800w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnk32x-p-1080.png 1080w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnk32x.png 1570w" alt="" class="mobile-presentation-left-brand-app">
                <img src="../img/smartmockups_kldneqvz.png" loading="lazy" width="310" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 100vw, 310px" srcset="../img/smartmockups_kldneqvz-p-500.png 500w, ../img/smartmockups_kldneqvz-p-800.png 800w, ../img/smartmockups_kldneqvz-p-1080.png 1080w, ../img/smartmockups_kldneqvz.png 1571w" alt="" class="mobile-presentation-rightest-brand-app">
                <img src="../img/smartmockups_kldnfsiz.png" loading="lazy" width="350" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 100vw, 350px" srcset="../img/smartmockups_kldnfsiz-p-500.png 500w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnfsiz-p-800.png 800w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnfsiz-p-1080.png 1080w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnfsiz.png 1571w" alt="" class="mobile-presentation-right-brand-app">
                <img src="../img/smartmockups_kldnld5u.png" loading="lazy" width="380" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 100vw, 380px" srcset="../img/smartmockups_kldnld5u-p-500.png 500w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnld5u-p-800.png 800w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnld5u-p-1080.png 1080w, ../img/smartmockups_kldnld5u.png 1480w" alt="" class="mobile-presentation-centre-brand-app">
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/**
 * index
 */

html, body { 
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}



body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #faf9f9;
    
}

.fixed-top{
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .fixed-top{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .navbar{
        display: none;
    }

    nav {
        height: 44px;
        
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.93);
    }
    
    nav ul {
        display: flex;
        height: 44px;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    
    nav a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: lighter;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    nav a:hover {
        color: #B8B8B8;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
      
    .navBar {
        max-width: 980px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

#collapsibleNavbar{
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-item a{
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar-brand {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

#navbar-icon-brand {
    height: 55px;
}


.navbar{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.93);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar-toggler {
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)!important;
}

.introduction-brand-innerpart {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

@media(min-width: 768px){
    
    #navbar-icon-brand {
        margin-top: 5px;
        height: 40px;
    }
    
    .introduction-brand-innerpart {
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 8rem;
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.heading {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
}

.sub-heading {
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.sub-sub-heading {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: -5px;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #a6a6a6;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }

.linking {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 10px;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.linking a{
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) { 
    .heading {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        color: #000;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    .sub-heading {
        margin-top: -10px;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        color: #000;
        font-size: 26px;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    
    .sub-sub-heading {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        margin-top: -5px;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        color: #a6a6a6;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: lighter;
      }
    
    .linking {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 10px;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    .linking a{
        display: block;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: 0.3s;
        padding-right: 35px;
        padding-left: 35px;
        font-weight: bolder;
    }
}



@media (min-width: 992px) { 
    .heading {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
        color: #000;
        font-size: 80px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    .sub-heading {
        margin-top: -10px;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        color: #000;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    
    .sub-sub-heading {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        margin-top: -5px;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        color: #a6a6a6;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: lighter;
      }
    
    .linking {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 10px;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    .linking a{
        display: block;
        font-size: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: 0.3s;
        padding-right: 35px;
        padding-left: 35px;
        font-weight: bolder;
    }
}


.mobile-presentation {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1px none #000;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 98.4%, 0);
    left: -50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.mobile-presentation-leftest {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: -70px;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
}

.mobile-presentation-left {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: -45px;
    width: 160px;
    height: auto;
}

.mobile-presentation-rightest {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 85px;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
}

.mobile-presentation-right {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 51px;
    width: 160px;
    height: auto;
}

.mobile-presentation-centre {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 170px;
    height: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .mobile-presentation-leftest {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: -110px;
        width: 170px;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    .mobile-presentation-left {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 25px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: -70px;
        width: 190px;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    .mobile-presentation-rightest {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: 135px;
        width: 170px;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    .mobile-presentation-right {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 25px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: 77px;
        width: 190px;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    .mobile-presentation-centre {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        width: 200px;
        height: auto;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .mobile-presentation {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        border: 1px none #000;
        background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 98.4%, 0);
        left: -50%;
    }
    
    .mobile-presentation-leftest {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 134px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: 11px;
        width: auto;
    }
    
    .mobile-presentation-left {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin-top: -504px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: 90px;
        width: auto;
    }
    
    .mobile-presentation-rightest {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin-top: -508px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: 585px;
        width: auto;
    }
    
    .mobile-presentation-right {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin-top: -504px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: 465px;
        width: auto;
    }
    
    .mobile-presentation-centre {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin-top: -584px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        width: auto;
    }
}

#cut-phones {
    height: 350px;
    position: static;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1px none #000;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 98.4%, 0);
    left: -50%;
    
}

/**
 *
 * Brand App
 *
 */

 .mobile-presentation-brand-app {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 14rem;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 1px none #000;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 98.4%, 0);
}

.mobile-presentation-leftest-brand-app  {
position: relative;
display: block;
margin-top: 134px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: 122px;
width: auto;
}

.mobile-presentation-left-brand-app  {
position: relative;
display: block;
margin-top: -504px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: 212px;
width: auto;
}

.mobile-presentation-rightest-brand-app  {
position: relative;
display: block;
margin-top: -508px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: 656px;
width: auto;
}

.mobile-presentation-right-brand-app  {
position: relative;
display: block;
margin-top: -504px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: 535px;
width: auto;
}

.mobile-presentation-centre-brand-app  {
position: relative;
display: block;
margin-top: -584px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: auto;
}
```

I thought the problem might come from my head, but as you can see, they are identical.

The resolutions are the following:

Index resolution: 1903 x 733

[image: picture from where I got the resolution for index page]

SecondPage resolution: 2114.44 x 904.12

[image: picture from where I got the resolution for second page]

The resolution doesn't differ, even when I delete all html code.

The resolution difference is done by my browser. When I look at the responsive design of the site, everything is fine. But as soon as I start to use the site without the responsive tool by Chrome, the navbar starts moving when I switch from one page to another. This is because the resolution of the second page is wider than my index page.

I just tried the site on Edge. Everything works fine there. The site does not become wider by itself. But this still doesn't fix my problem on Chrome.

Any idea why Chrome behaves so weird?

Comment: Please add your style.css as well, you may have written non-responsive styling which is causing this issue

Comment: I have added addtitional html and css code, hopefully it will help. Thanks in advance for trying to help me.

Comment: I tried the code, there was no problem. Where did you look at the resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "error" was that I zoomed out of the window and Chrome saved the zoom preferences. Additionally the page had no scrollbar like the other pages and therefore was not pushed to the side.